# Sort column names using wildcard using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have a big dataframe with more than 100 columns. I am sharing a miniature version of my real dataframe below

```
ID  rev_Q1   rev_Q5     rev_Q4    rev_Q3   rev_Q2  tx_Q3   tx_Q5  tx_Q2  tx_Q1  tx_Q4
1     1        1         1         1        1       1       1      1       1       1
2     1        1         1         1        1       1       1      1       1       1
```

I would like to do the below

a) sort the column names based on Quarters (ex:Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5..Q100..Q1000) for each column pattern

b) By column pattern, I mean the keyword that is before underscore which is `rev` and `tx`.

So, I tried the below but it doesn't work and it also shifts the `ID` column to the back

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

I expect my output to be like as below. In real time, there are more than 100 columns with more than 30 patterns like `rev`, `tx` etc. I want my `ID` column to be in the first position as shown below.

```
ID  rev_Q1   rev_Q2     rev_Q3    rev_Q4   rev_Q5  tx_Q1   tx_Q2  tx_Q3  tx_Q4  tx_Q5
1     1        1         1         1        1       1       1      1       1       1
2     1        1         1         1        1       1       1      1       1       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the provided example, `df.sort_index(axis=1)` should work fine.

If you have Q values higher that 9, use natural sorting with [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/):

```
from natsort import natsort_key

out = df.sort_index(axis=1, key=natsort_key)
```

Or using manual sorting with `np.lexsort`:

```
idx = df.columns.str.split('_Q', expand=True, n=1)
order = np.lexsort([idx.get_level_values(1).astype(float), idx.get_level_values(0)])

out = df.iloc[:, order]
```

Comment: nice but it puts `Q10,Q11, Q12` etc after `Q1`. So, it results in incorrect output like `Q1,Q10,Q11,Q12,Q2,Q3,Q4....`

Comment: I mean with natsort

Comment: Strange, try with the `lexsort` alternative

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```py
new_order = list(df.columns)
new_order = ['ID'] + sorted(new_order.remove("ID"))

df = df[new_order]
```

we manually put `"ID"` in front and then sort what is remaining

Comment: same issue as below answer. It puts `Q10,Q11, Q12` etc after `Q1`. So, it results in incorrect output like `Q1,Q10,Q11,Q12,Q2,Q3,Q4....`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to create a dataframe from the column names. Create two columns: one for Variable and another one for Quarter number. Finally sort this dataframe by values then extract index.

```
idx = (df.columns.str.extract(r'(?P<V>[^_]+)_Q(?P<Q>\d+)')
         .fillna(0).astype({'Q': int})
         .sort_values(by=['V', 'Q']).index)

df = df.iloc[:, idx]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID  rev_Q1  rev_Q2  rev_Q3  rev_Q4  rev_Q5  tx_Q1  tx_Q2  tx_Q3  tx_Q4  tx_Q5
0   1       1       1       1       1       1      1      1      1      1      1
1   2       1       1       1       1       1      1      1      1      1      1

>>> (df.columns.str.extract(r'(?P<V>[^_]+)_Q(?P<Q>\d+)')
         .fillna(0).astype({'Q': int})
         .sort_values(by=['V', 'Q']))
      V  Q
0     0  0
1   rev  1
5   rev  2
4   rev  3
3   rev  4
2   rev  5
9    tx  1
8    tx  2
6    tx  3
10   tx  4
7    tx  5
```

Comment: Nice. what does `V` mean here? I understand `Q` is for char match but what is `V`?

Comment: V for variable. Q for quarters